# Empty bash variable eating up start of next one?

Tags: linux, bash

I was recently editing a startup script to add command-line flags to a Java program if the bash script was launched with an environment variable present.

The relevant part:

```
  ACTIVE_HEAPDUMP=""

  if [ "$ENABLE_HEAPDUMP" == "true" ]; then
    echo 'Heapdump enabled'
    ACTIVE_HEAPDUMP="-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/solr-4.8.0"
  else
    echo 'Heapdump NOT enabled'
    ACTIVE_HEAPDUMP=""
  fi
```

With this startup command, everything works as expected:

```
$JAVA $SOLR_START_OPTS $ACTIVE_HEAPDUMP $SOLR_ADDL_ARGS -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="$SOLR_TIP/bin/oom_solr.sh $SOLR_PORT" -jar start.jar
```

However, with this startup command, it fails:

```
$JAVA $SOLR_START_OPTS $SOLR_ADDL_ARGS $ACTIVE_HEAPDUMP -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="$SOLR_TIP/bin/oom_solr.sh $SOLR_PORT" -jar start.jar
```

The difference is the location of `$ACTIVE_HEAPDUMP`. The working version has it **before** `$SOLR_ADDL_ARGS`, the not-working version has it **after** that.

`$SOLR_ADDL_ARGS` is empty.

The error message is:

> Unrecognized VM option 'HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
>   -XX:HeapDumpPath=...' Did you mean '(+/-)HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'?

As you can see, the problem is that the initial `-XX:+` is gone. Just not there anymore.

This is a behavior of bash I did not know about and also have not been able to find any documentation on. What's going on here?

Comment: You need to quote all shell variables on your command line.

Comment: @anubhava: In this case, it wouldn't help, as the variable contains a space and two actual command line options.

Comment: Have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Try running your code with `set -xv` to see how bash expands the variables.

Comment: For your [mcve], you should probably prefix your command with `printf '%q\n'` or similar, so that you can see how the shell splits arguments.

Comment: I always recommend using bash arrays to manage argument lists, as they handle any spaces in the lists and the lists can be empty.